# Seperate cron.yaml per worker server

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk with ruby on rails. I am trying to separate all my SQS ques and have successfully done that so my server setup is like so

`development__mailers`

`development__cron`

`development__notifications`

`development__payments`

This all works fine however the problem I am running into is that I have a `cron.yaml` file that gets loaded onto every server with the following code (truncated)

```
version: 1
cron:
  - name: "SetOverdueStatusJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 * * * *"

  # 18:00 => 2AM CN time
  - name: "Statistics::ComputeDailyKpiJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 18 * * *"

  - name: "ProductStatusCheckJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 0 * * *"

  - name: "Jobs::Order::ResolvePayingJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0,20,40 * * * *"

  - name: "Jobs::Payment::SynchronizeJob"
    url: "/periodic_stasks"
    schedule: "0 * * * *"

  # Notify Slack with order count
  - name: "OrdersCheckNotifierJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 1,6,8 * * *"
```

So my question here is how can I disable some of these jobs per server on aws so that I am not sending the same job 4 times?